# how to conver the array of undefined to a array of string

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

I trying to pass the array value from frontend to the backend, while transmitting the value i facing some errors

this is my response data

```
{
  sender: 'venkat',
  numbers: '[919361667266, 919361667266, 919361667266, 919361667266]',
  message: 'hiii'
}
```

I need to convert this number data this
`'[919361667266, 919361667266, 919361667266, 919361667266]'`

to

```
'["919361667266", "919361667266", "919361667266", "919361667266"]'
```

the error i faced while parsing

```
const numbers = JSON.parse(req.body.numbers);


(node:27058) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: SyntaxError: Unexpected token @ in JSON at position 13
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at /Users/
```

Comment: There is no `@` sign in `req.body.numbers` so there is something else going on. If you try `JSON.parse(req.body.numbers)` with the data you provided above, it will work fine.

Comment: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: data.map is not a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Frontend is sending `'[919361667266, 919361667266, 919361667266, 919361667266]'`

What you can do is convert that string to an array of strings: `response.numbers.split(/\D+/).filter(s => !!s)`

Code:

```js
const response = {
  sender: 'venkat',
  numbers: '[919361667266, 919361667266, 919361667266, 919361667266]',
  message: 'hiii'
}
const numbers = JSON.stringify(response.numbers.split(/\D+/).filter(s => !!s))
const str = JSON.stringify({
  ...response,
  numbers
})
const obj = JSON.parse(str)

console.log('Result Str: ', str)
console.log('Result Obj: ', obj)
```

Comment: this is what the output is `{"sender":"venkat","numbers":[919361667266,919361667266,919361667266],"message":"iiiii"}`. but i need the array of number to be convert to array of string like this ["919361667266","919361667266","919361667266"]

Comment: Updated answer to array of strings instead of numbers

Answer (score 0):

You are not sending proper JSON. JSON used double quotes around the key and string values

```json
{
  "sender": "venkat",
  "numbers": "[919361667266, 919361667266, 919361667266, 919361667266]",
  "message": "hiii"
}
```

Alternatively, you could stringify your object

```js
const payload = JSON.stringify({
  sender: 'venkat',
  numbers: '[919361667266, 919361667266, 919361667266, 919361667266]',
  message: 'hiii'
});
```

Comment: But they only try to parse `req.body.numbers` and that's a valid JSON.

Comment: is there is any way to convert this string `'[919361667266, 919361667266, 919361667266, 919361667266]'` to array like `["919361667266", "919361667266", "919361667266", "919361667266"]`

Comment: Yes, you have to transform the string to an array and convert each number to a string.

`const payload = { numbers: '[919361667266, 919361667266, 919361667266, 919361667266]' }

payload.numbers.split(/\D+/).filter(Boolean)`

Answer (score 0):

After `JOSN.parse` the `numbers` param be an array of numbers, this is the case  in the response because the server is sending an array of numbers. So you can either handle it in the server side or the client side

**At Server Side**

Before sending response stringily the values in the `numbers` array

`numbers.map(val => val.toString())`

OR

**At Client Side**

Parse it and convert it to string

`JSON.parse(numbers).map(val => val.toString())`